# appwrite type String is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, appwrite

Sorry if the title is not descriptive enough,

I've managed to self host an appwrite on a private cloud, on a container, which incoming traffic is managed by Nginx Proxy Manager

I can connect to the appwrite SDK with flutter, I can use database.listDocuments and database.getDocument with no issue

the current collection only have 1 document, which created manually using web, so using database.listDocument will return a list of document with length of 1

my current issue is I cannot use database.createDocument, and database.updateDocument

```
Future<void> createRankings() async {
apwr.Databases database = apwr.Databases(client);
String docID = "BDRec0000001";
List<String> permission = [
  Permission.read(Role.any()),
  Permission.update(Role.any()),
];

try {
  var response = await database.createDocument(
    databaseId: dbID,
    collectionId: collectionID,
    documentId: docID,
    data: {"item": 1, "itemMake": 1, "sn": "GHTDD001Z001"},
    permissions: permission,
  );

} catch (e) {
  print('Error creating document: $e');
}}
```

the return in flutter is Error creating document : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

so I dig further and i found this code in
appwrite-9.0.0/lib/services/database.dart (the source of method createDocument)
on the line inside createDocument's method

```
Future<models.Document> createDocument(
  {required String databaseId,
  required String collectionId,
  required String documentId,
  required Map data,
  List<String>? permissions}) async {
final String path = '/databases/{databaseId}/collections/{collectionId}/documents'
    .replaceAll('{databaseId}', databaseId)
    .replaceAll('{collectionId}', collectionId);

final Map<String, dynamic> params = {
  'documentId': documentId,
  'data': data,
  'permissions': permissions,
};

final Map<String, String> headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
};

final res = await client.call(HttpMethod.post, path: path, params: params, headers: headers);
print(res.data);
print('path:$path');
print('params:$params');
print('headers:$headers');
return models.Document.fromMap(res.data);}
```

I've added the line print(res.data) and the 3 others to see what is the data returned

and the result printed is

```
flutter: <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried seeking this issue in their github and also here, nothing related to it

I'm pretty sure it is something simple, but I cant find any answer anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check that you're using https for your endpoint as part of `client.setEndpoint()`. If you don't and Appwrite has force HTTPS enabled, you would see that 301 moved since Appwrite redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: did you mean on my definition of serverEndpoint
i need to use String serverEndpoint = 'https://myserverDomain.com/v1'; instead of String serverEndpoint = 'http://myserverDomain.com/v1';?

Comment: Uh I can't quite tell the difference between those two options you shared...I was suggesting to use `https://myserverDomain.com/v1` instead of `http://myserverDomain.com/v1`.

Comment: ah yes thats what i typed, but i guess it was converted into a hyperlink isntead, but yes, thats what i asked https instead of http, ok ill check the codes again. thanks